# Javascript JSON.Parse method fails on clean json data - syntax error unexpected token

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I have a js file that contains json nodes.  This file is read into my program, into a string, and then i run JSON.parse on it:

```
var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
client.open('GET', 'data/data.js');

//when the file has been loaded, this will execute 
client.onreadystatechange = function() 
{
    if(client.responseText != "")
    {
        ScanText(client.responseText);
    }
}
function ScanText(text)
{
    var json;
    try
    {
        var cleanedText = text;
        cleanedText = cleanedText.replace('Var', '');
        cleanedText = cleanedText.replace('arrayName', '');
        cleanedText = cleanedText.replace('=','')

        alert(cleanedText);
        json = JSON.parse(cleanedText);  //Issue happens here
        alert('try');
    }
    catch (ex)
    {
        alert(ex);
    }   
}
```

My datafile looks like:

```
[

{
AollName:'YUI678',
Contract:'123-33'
},
{
TollName:'YUI678',
Contract:'123-33'
}
]
```

I get the error 'Syntax Error: Unexpected token A', which comes from the first node AollName.

Why cant the json.parse method run on this input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your file does not contain valid [JSON](http://json.org/).

JSON keys must be quoted, and string values must use double quotes. Just because it might execute as a valid JavaScript object, does not mean that it is valid JSON (the data interchange format).

```
[
    {
        "AollName": "YUI678",
        "Contract": "123-33"
    },
    {
        "TollName": "YUI678",
        "Contract": "123-33"
    }
]
```

would be valid.

Answer (score 2):

You're using invalid JSON. Strings need to be enclosed with double quotes:

```
[
    {
        "AollName": "YUI678",
        "Contract": "123-33"
    },
    {
        "TollName": "YUI678",
        "Contract": "123-33"
    }
]
```

Add [JSONLint](http://www.jsonlint.com) to your workflow.